# How can i manage exceptions from Client.PostAsync<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can i manage exceptions from Client.PostAsync ?

I have this code:

```
            AzureDevOpsSearchApiResponse searchResults = await client.PostAsync<AzureDevOpsSearchApiResponse>
            (SiteGlobal.AzureDevOpsSearchRestApi, searchRequest.AsJson());
```

but i may not have status code "200" or maybe there was other issue.
how can i manage & handle the exception that may appear from the response?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking here? Are you asking how to catch exceptions? And what is `client`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It doesn't appear to be `HttpClient` since `PostAsync` is a generic method here.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to send http post request.
everything work well and i get answer back.
but i want to catch any exception from it like i have with HttpResponseMessage:
EnsureSuccessStatusCode() // Throw exception if not a success code.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034199/properly-handling-httpclient-exceptions-within-async-await) ? You can find the exceptions it can throw [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes i have a generic function:

 public virtual async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string requestUrl, HttpContent content)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);
            var t = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
@John

Comment: Ok i have succeeded to resolve this thanks ;)